# What's the equivalent of this Logarithmic expression? [Probability Functions]

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory, density-function

I'm having some trouble with the following application:

Let $f$ be the function defined on R by:

$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
a.3^{-x}&\textrm{if }x>0\\
a.3^x&\textrm{if }x<0.
\end{array}\right.
$

**1)** Determine $a$ so that $f$ is a PDF.

**2)**  Let X be a random variable that admits $f$ as a density. Give the CDF of X. Show that X admits an expectation $E(X)$ and calculate it.

**3)** We set $Y=3^X$. Give the CDF of $Y$.

I know that for $f$ to be a PDF one of the conditions is it has to integrate to 1, so I did that and computed $a$ to be equal to $a=\frac{\ln 3}{2}$ for $f$ to be a PDF.

I also have no problem on question $2)$

For $x<0$ **:**

$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{x}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{-\infty}} \dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)}{2}{\cdot}3^z\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}z}$ = $\dfrac{3^x}{2}$

And for $x>0$ **:**

$F(x)=F(0)+\int_0^xe^{-z\ln 3}dz=1-\frac{3^{-x}}{2}$

What I'm struggling with is question $3)$

I understand that we should compute:
$P(Y<x) = P(3^X<x) = P(X <\frac{\ln(x)}{ln(3)})$

I understand the concept up to this point, but after this I don't get how in the solution to this problem, they computed:

> ***If $0<x<1$:***
>
> $F_Y(x)=\frac{1}{2}3^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}}=\frac{x}{2}$
>
> ***If $x>1$:***
>
> $F_Y(x)=1-\frac{1}{2}3^{-\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}}=1-\frac{1}{2x}$

There are two things I'm struggling with when it comes to this question:

**1)** Why did they take only positive $x$ values? My guess is it's because of the Natural Logarithm's domain of definition. But if that's the case, why did they take values from 0 to 1. Why exactly 1?

**2)** I don't understand how they went from $\frac{1}{2}3^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}}$ to $\frac{x}{2}$. I tried to find some properties for that but in vain. How do we simplify to that?

Sorry if this was too long. I just wanted to give some context. I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: $3^{t} = e^{t\ln 3}$, so $3^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}} = ....$

Comment: It's going to simplify, I see now. Thanks a lot ! Hope it's not too much to ask but do you know something about the first question?

Comment: I reckon what's confusing you is that they also use the letter $x$ when discussing the cdf of $Y$. (It's correct, but for the sake of reading it, replace $x$ by $y$ everywhere). When $X\in\mathbb{R}$, then $Y=3^X > 0$ (it's always positive: check the graph of $3^x$ if you have a doubt). So for $y \leq 0$, $F_Y(y) = 0$. That's why they only deal with $y>0$...

Comment: I see. However I don't understand for example in the case if $0 < y < 1$ why did we plug the value of $y$ in the CDF that we previously found for $x<0$ ? I don't get the intuiton behind that.

Comment: The reason to break it into cases with $0 < x < 1$ and $x \geq 1$ is from the pdf of $X$. If $0 < x < 1$, then $\ln(x) / \ln(3) < 0$, meaning that $P(X < \ln(x) / \ln(3))$ puts you in the first case of $X$'s pdf. Then $x \geq 1$ puts you in the other case.

Comment: I understand the rationale behind it now. As @ClementC. said I got confused by the x's. I see now that they mean different things in different cases. Thanks a lot !